# Applying functions in list column to column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for the most elegant approach for this operation. I currently have a tibble containing a few list-columns of models and a column containing my test dataset for prediction.

I can manually compute the predictions for each model using `dplyr :: mutate` but I was wondering if there is some lapply or loop that could quicken the process.

````
lab_formula <- as.formula("pop ~ lifeExp ")
temp_formula <- as.formula("gdpPercap ~ year")
last_formula <- as.formula("year ~ gdpPercap")
formula_list <- list(lab_formula,temp_formula,last_formula)


country_model <- function(df, formula_list, index) {
  list(lm(formula = formula_list[[index]] , data = df), 
       randomForest(formula=formula_list[[index]], data = df),
       gbm(formula=formula_list[[index]], data = df, n.minobsinnode = 2))
}

by_country <- gapminder %>% 
  dplyr :: group_by(country, continent) %>% 
  nest()

df1 <- by_country %>% 
  mutate(model1 = map(data, ~country_model(., formula_list, 1)), 
         model2 = map(data, ~country_model(., formula_list, 2)),
         model3 = map(data, ~country_model(., formula_list, 3))
         )

pred_1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(pred_1= map2(data,model1, function(x, y) 
    map(seq_along(y), function(i) 
      if (i == 3) predict(y[[i]], n.trees = y[[i]]$n.trees)
      else as.numeric(predict(y[[i]])))))

Is there an elegant code to apply model1, model2, model3 on the data column? And to subsequently extract the predictions from each list of models embedded within the list column? (something to do with ```unnest```)

   country      data              model1     model2     model3     pred_1    
   <fct>       <list>            <list>     <list>     <list>     <list>    
 1 Afghanistan <tibble [12 x 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
 2 Albania     <tibble [12 x 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
 3 Algeria     <tibble [12 x 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
 4 Angola     <tibble [12 x 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
 5 Argentina  <tibble [12 x 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]>


Desired Outcome:
 country   data   model1     model2     model3   pred_1 pred_2 pred_3
````

Comment: Sorry about that! Corrected the code

Comment: @akrun could you show me the code please?

Comment: Is it flexible to change the `country_model` function

Comment: Advisable not to...

Comment: ok go ahead, lets see!

Comment: I just saw someone using `purrr:reduce2()` on GitHub [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4441#issuecomment-506229857), and it struck me that this approach might be able to help you in some way (although your problem seems more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

We could create the functions with `switch` to recognize the correct model and then use `map` to loop over the columns created

```
library(randomForest)
library(gbm)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
```

-functions

```
country_model <- function(df, formula,  model_name) {
         switch(model_name, 

         "model1" = lm(formula = formula , data = df),
         "model2" = randomForest(formula= formula, data = df),
         "model3" = gbm(formula=formula, data = df, n.minobsinnode = 2)

      )


} 

country_pred <- function(model, model_name) {

 switch(model_name,

    "model1" =  as.numeric(predict(model)),
    "model2" = as.numeric(predict(model)),
    "model3" = predict(model, n.trees = model[["n.trees"]]) 

 )


}
```

Set the names of formula list with the model names

```
fmlst <- set_names(formula_list, str_c("model", seq_along(formula_list)))
```

Create the model columns separately with `imap`

```
df1 <- imap_dfc(fmlst, ~ by_country %>%
                              transmute(!! .y := map(data, 
            country_model, formula = .x, model_name = .y ))) %>%
                                      bind_cols(by_country, .)


str1 <- names(df1)[startsWith(names(df1), "model")]
str2 <- str_c("pred_", 1:3)
```

Create the prediction columns as well

```
df2 <- map_dfc(str1, ~ {

 nm1 <- .x
  df1 %>% 
      select(.x) %>%   
        pull(1) %>%
        map(., country_pred, model_name = nm1) %>%
        list



 }
 ) %>%
  rename_all(~ str2) %>%
  bind_cols(df1, .)

df2
# A tibble: 142 x 9
#   country     continent data              model1 model2     model3 pred_1     pred_2     pred_3    
#   <fct>       <fct>     <list>            <list> <list>     <list> <list>     <list>     <list>    
# 1 Afghanistan Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
# 2 Albania     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
# 3 Algeria     Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
# 4 Angola      Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
# 5 Argentina   Americas  <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
# 6 Australia   Oceania   <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
# 7 Austria     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
# 8 Bahrain     Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
# 9 Bangladesh  Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#10 Belgium     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <lm>   <rndmFrs.> <gbm>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
# … with 132 more rows
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, thanks for helping out but what I wanted was to apply all 3 models within each instance (in the model list column) on the 'data' set. Then do the matching...

I will elaborate on this request in the answer my question tab

Comment: @MatthewLoh I think your requirement didn't make any sense to me.  Here, I am storing 3 columns separately for model1, 2, and 3, and corresponding preds

Answer (score -1):

Basically, I am trying to use a for loop to loop through all my stored variable names, apply the models 1/2/3 on it and subsequently use these names to create new variable columns in my existing df1 dataframe.

```
pred_names <- c('labour_pred','temp_pred', 'last_pred') 


for (c in seq_along(pred_names)) { 
model_pred <- df1 %>% 
mutate(pred_names[c] = map2(data_2018,model_list[c], function(x, y) 
map(seq_along(y), function(i) 
if (i == 3) predict(y[[i]], n.trees = y[[i]]$n.trees) 
else as.numeric(predict(y[[i]]))))) 
}
```

```
However, I get these errors instead:
Error: unexpected '=' in: 
" model_pred <- model_fit %>% 
mutate(pred_names[c] =" 

Error: unexpected ')' in: 
" if (i == 3) predict(y[[i]], n.trees = y[[i]]$n.trees) 
else as.numeric(predict(y[[i]]))))" 
> } 
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```